# What is the best way to write multiple if tags that compare two variables

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am a beginner in C# coding, and I was trying to compare two `int` variables (C#).

```
void CompareNumber() {
    int oneNumber;
    int secondNumber;

    if (oneNumber > secondNumber)
        {
        DoSomething();
        }

    else if (oneNumber < secondnumber)
        {
        DoSomethingElse();
        }

    else if (oneNumber == secondnumber)
         {
         DoSomethingDifferent();
         }
}
```

While this does work, it looks kinda messy, especially because I compare variables in this manner many times. Is there a more concise way of doing this, making it look neater? (Except for omitting the curly brackets)

Comment: Check the [switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) statement

Comment: @JoshPart you can't use `switch` to compare using `<` or `>` operators.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your current code. The only change you can make it remove last `if` statement, because it will be always true if both checks above returned false.

Comment: Oh, ok. The reason I ask is because I use that so many times that it looks kinda messy. So for the last bit @MarcinJuraszek I would just remove the if bit (I still need the else)?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek my bad. I think I "visual basic-ed" a little

Comment: Yes, you need the else. You could probably write a helper method for that, but I don't think that would be readable.

Comment: You could also write it in one line, althouhgt that sacrifices a little readability.

Comment: I know you can ommit the curly brackets and that you can simply write it on the same line, I was just wondering if there was code made specifically to compare all possible outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you already wrote it is the best way :) There is absolutely nothing wrong with it.

However, when you say "especially because I compare variables in this manner many times", there may be something to fix there. Ideally, you should be able to reuse what you wrote one time.

Comment: I always do the idea where I compare if one int is bigger, smaller or equal to another. Is there a way to make it that I can reuse what I write one time?

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen it is very hard to suggest refactoring without seeing code you trying to re-wirte. Consider posting *working* code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour if you need refactoring suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're asking for general ways to make if statements look tidier, consider the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) "?:" if you're assigning a value.  It doesn't work for calling void functions, but if, for instance, you wanted to return the higher of the two int values with CompareNumber(), you could do this:

```
int CompareNumber(int first, int second)
{
    return first > second ? first : second;
}
```

Can't say I see any simple ways to make your sample code more elegant though.  If you have three different cases to implement, you can't skip anything.  Of course I could be smart alec and simplify your function for you (and it wouldn't have errors for using uninitialized variables):

```
void CompareNumber()
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

EDIT:  Previously stated you can't call functions with the conditional operator, but I meant you can't call void functions... they must return a value or you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: How would you be able to do the last section?

Comment: Rufus L is right, you can chain the operator.  However, he's wrong to say they work just like the if/else.  If "DoSomething()" or the others are void functions, it will not compile (at least not in Visual Studios 2013, where I tested it; "error CS0201").

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten it using ternary operators, but you're doing it correctly.

```
void CompareNumber(int first, int second) {

    (first > second)
        ? DoSomething()
        : (second > first)
            ? DoSomethingElse()
            : DoSomethingDifferent();
}
```

Comment: Ahh, Ok. My issue here is that can it run a method/function (Since one of the previous answers said you cannot) If so, I still don't think I would use this, ONLY because it sacrifices a lot of readability.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? You can run this sample as a method - just pass in two integers! This allows re-use, as long as you always want to do the same thing for the conditional checks.

Comment: The answer below says you can;t use conditionals to call functions. Is this true?

Comment: Absolutely not. They work the same as a regular 'if / else', just shortened syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `switch` on the signum of the delta:

```
switch ( Math.Sign( Alpha - Beta ) )
{
case -1: // Alpha < Beta.
    // Do something.
    break;
case 0: // Alpha == Beta.
    // Do something.
    break;
case 1: // Alpha > Beta.
    // Do something.        
}
```

You can, of course, use the `default` clause in the `switch` to handle the final case.

Comment: You're comparing two values and, based on their relative values, executing one of three pieces of code. If you subtract one value from the other then the resulting difference will tell you which value was bigger (the difference will be greater or less than zero) or if they were equal (the difference will be zero). `Math.Sign` changes that to a simple `1`, `0` or `-1`. Try it.

Comment: I see. So we would swap alpha and beta with the two int variables?

Comment: Yes, we would. [`Math.Sign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sign%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?ppud=4) supports a variety of data types.

Comment: Honestly, this just makes the code harder to read/understand while adding no value.

Comment: @EdS. - It certainly doesn't clarify the purpose of the code. It does have the advantage of not having to repeat the variable names several times, which could reduce cut'n'paste errors if there are a large number comparisons being performed as stated by the OP. And it demonstrates that a practical solution using `switch` is possible without refuting MarcinJuraszek's comment on the question.

Comment: If I were to use coding, and know others were going to look at it, I would have to make sure to put comments on each case to explain what the heck is going on :)

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen - If you have to repeat the same block of code frequently, as mentioned in your question, you should be able to explain it once and use it freely thereafter. It's not like your passing two values and three lamdas to a method that handles the decision making. I'm guessing that you if you go back and look at some code that you wrote a year (or decade) ago that you'll think that some of the comments are pretty unnecessary and some of the code is pretty funny.

Comment: I only started coding a week ago, so I don't have much to base off :)